# Delete last column value, move values and add new value in the first column

Tags: python, mysql, sql, data-structures

I am trying to figure out the fastest way for the following problem.

I have a table with 10 columns.

Whenever I run a script, it should delete the value from 10th column and move values to right, i.e 9th column should be moved to 10th , 8th - 7th and so on. I will add new value in the 1st column.

I am using Python and MySQL.

Comment: Show a code example, you'll likely get more feedback.

Comment: Knowing the strengths of both python and SQL, I see no easy solution to this in SQL. Not as easy as it can be done in python using pandas, the canonical data manipulation package for python. I can provide more help if code examples are provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tbl
    SET c10 = c9,
        c9 = c8,
        c7 = c6,
        ...
        c2 = c1,
        c1 = 'new value';
```

One SQL statement, it will churn through the entire table.

If "new value" is not a constant, it gets messier.

Why in blazes are you manipulating a table like this???

Comment: @ Rick James, I have a table with two columns key & value.  I need to have the history of that value whenever it is changed. So, I am planing to have  another table with 10 columns and update that table whenever the value is updated.